# Unpacking and rebuilding rpm packages

Tags: linux, rpm

I'm interested in unpacking an rpm so I can get at the files without having to go through the install process. There don't seem to be any options for this using either the `yum` or `rpm` commands. My goal is to then modify and then rebuild the rpm. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could unpack rpm using command

```
rpm2cpio package.rpm | cpio -i --make-directories
```

If you want to modify package, the better way is to download package.src.rpm file, install it using `rpm -i package.src.rpm`. This would place sources to /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES. You could patch sources and modify spec file located in /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/ and then rebuild package using

```
rpmbuild -bb /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/package.spec
```

Comment: I don't file /usr/src/redhat

Comment: yumdownloader (in yum-utils package) is handy for snagging srpms.

Comment: the directory /usr/src/redhat should be created, when you install your first source rpm.